# ROLLUP on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm counting the number of of entities that have been received between 2 dates or have been resolved between those same 2 dates, and then grouping them by their source.

Currently my code is

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(EntitySource) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE EntitySource END EntitySource, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(PostmarkDate) 
        FROM tblEntity t1
        Where ((PostmarkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)) AND t1.EntitySource = t.EntitySource
    ) AS Recieved, 
    COUNT(ResolDate) AS Completed
FROM tblEntity t
WHERE 
    (IsCompleted = '1' AND (ResolDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)) OR ( (PostmarkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate))
GROUP BY EntitySource WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN EntitySource = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Using this query results in a table of

```
EntitySource    Recieved    Completed
D               79          175
B               272         614
C               19          13
E               1           6
A               1           0
F               3           12
Total           0           820
```

As you can see ROLLUP is correctly totaling up the completed entities column, but it's not adding up the received column at all. The total for that column should be displaying 375, giving a total row of

```
Total           375         820
```

Comment: You have no aggregating function on that field, so I would imagine that would not allow it to work as you expect. put a SUM in front of it and see if that works.

Comment: so SUM(SELECT COUNT(PostmarkDate) ... ) AS recieved?

It's giving me, "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." when i try

Comment: Refactor that subquery into a join instead and then use COUNT(postmarkdate)

Comment: Except that count includes the resolved entities as well (things are postmarked before they're resolved), which is why i had to subquery it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rollup works on the aggregate functions.
So counting or summing a CASE also does the trick.

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(EntitySource,'Total') AS EntitySource,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN PostmarkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN 1 END) AS Received, 
   COUNT(ResolDate) AS Completed
 FROM tblEntity t
 WHERE 
 (
      (IsCompleted = '1' AND ResolDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)     
   OR (PostmarkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
 )
 GROUP BY EntitySource WITH ROLLUP
 ORDER BY
 GROUPING(EntitySource),
 (CASE EntitySource
  WHEN 'D' THEN 1
  WHEN 'B' THEN 2
  WHEN 'C' THEN 3
  WHEN 'E' THEN 4
  WHEN 'A' THEN 5
  WHEN 'F' THEN 6
  ELSE 9
  END)
```